# VS Code does not display changes in cloned repository (as a subdirectory of another repository) in source control

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm following the instructions [in DeepMind's TapNet repo](https://github.com/deepmind/tapnet):

> 1. Install ffmpeg on your machine:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt update
>    sudo apt install ffmpeg
>    ```
> 2. Install OpenEXR:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install libopenexr-dev
>    ```
> 3. Clone the repository:
>
>    ```
>    git clone https://github.com/deepmind/tapnet.git
>    ```
> 4. Add current path (parent directory of where TapNet is installed) to PYTHONPATH:
>
>    ```
>    export PYTHONPATH=`(cd ../ && pwd)`:`pwd`:$PYTHONPATH
>    ```
> 5. Switch to the project directory:
>
>    ```
>    cd tapnet
>    ```
> 6. Install kubric as a subdirectory:
>
>    ```
>    git clone https://github.com/google-research/kubric.git
>    ```
> 7. Install requirements:
>
>    ```
>    pip install -r requirements.txt
>    ```

I have cloned `tapnet` fine, and after that cloned the `kubric` repository as a subdirectory of `tapnet`'s.

So now I have:

```
/users/me/repos/my_tapnet_integration/tapnet/
/users/me/repos/my_tapnet_integration/tapnet/.git/
/users/me/repos/my_tapnet_integration/tapnet/kubric/
/users/me/repos/my_tapnet_integration/tapnet/kubric/.git/
```

I made some changes in `kubric/` and `tapnet/` and wanted to commit them to my_tapnet_integration repo. However, changes made in `kubric/` `tapnet/` and are not displayed in source control.

What should I do to make changes in `kubric/` appear in source control? `git submodule add kubric/`?

Comment: I wonder what happens if you add folder B to the .gitignore of repo A?

Comment: @Dai I need to integrate neural network into my software and I had to do that because it was necessary in order to install and run neural network

Comment: @neon5480 Please show me the instructions or steps that you're following that specifically tell you to nest git repos (because I don't believe that anyone would actually suggest that) - perhaps they meant you should be using git submodules or subtrees? If so, then that's not the same thing as a nested git repo directory, which is almost always a recipe for data-loss and corruption.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. It works for me even without adding the sub-repo folder to the parent-repo folder's gitignore.

Comment: It would be nice to have a procedure that minimall reproduces this issue (a [mre]), since I can't reproduce it with my basic attempt. Also, what version of VS Code do you have installed?

Comment: @user the OP wrote _"I had to do that because it was necessary in order to install and run neural network"_ - using language like "it was necessary in order to install..." strongly suggests they're just following readme/onboarding instructions on some dependency's repo... without applying critical-thinking.

Comment: @Dai here is a repo for neural network that I am integrating now: https://github.com/deepmind/tapnet. As you can see, to run nn inference, you should firstly clone tapnet and secondly clone kubric as a subdirectory. My integration script is located inside tapnet directory

Comment: @neon5480 Thank you for posting the link - I see what you mean now. I'll admit that I'm very surprised that they would tell people to do that - but I see it also makes the Python code simpler. I got nuffin'

Comment: @neon5480 I've taken the liberty of editing your post to show the actual instructions and what you've done (instead of obfuscating details...). HTH.

Comment: @Dai thanks, I have added some additional info (I want to commit these changes to my_tapnet_integration repo, so as tapnet and kubric are being shown as usual folders in my github repo)